# fails to load assets file on page reloading angularJS

Tags: angularjs, ngroute

I have the following routes:

```
/**
 * General app route
 */
angular
    .module('app')
    .config(config);

config.$inject = ['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider'];
function config($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'partials/index.html',
            controller: 'ImageController'
        })
        .when('/category/:name', {
            templateUrl: 'partials/index.html',
            controller: 'CategoryController',
        })
        .when('/404', {
            templateUrl: 'partials/404.html'
        })
        .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/404' });

    $locationProvider.html5Mode({
        enabled: true,
        requireBase: false
    });
}
```

when I'm trying to access the category route from base route it works fine, but when I reload the page on category route it tries to access the assets file through category path instead of base path.
how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out by adding `base` tag to `index.html`

```
<head>
    <base href="/index.html">
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is the disable HTML5 mode

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode({
    // enabled: true,
    requireBase: false
});
```

Other way is to make sure the server side routing returns correct HTML file.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, you're solutions works but I added html5mode for removing # from url.

Answer (score 0):

You have activate html5 mode, and for that you need redirect all the traffic to the index.html

See the section html5 mode for more details https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location